Combobox fieldbacground change python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ComboboxColorChanger:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Combobox Color Change")
        self.root.geometry("300x150")

        # Create a Combobox
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.root, values=["", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"], state="readonly")
        self.combobox.grid(pady=20, padx=50)

        # Bind events to handle user actions
        self.combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.update_combobox_style)

        # Initial style configuration
        self.set_combobox_background(self.combobox)

    def set_combobox_background(self, widget):
        """Set the background color of the Combobox based on its selection state."""
        value = widget.get()
        style = ttk.Style()

        if value == "Option 1":  # Option 1 selected
            style.configure("Red.TCombobox", fieldbackground="#ffcccc", background="#ffcccc")
            widget.configure(style="Red.TCombobox")
        elif value == "":  # No option selected
            style.configure("CyanLight.TCombobox", fieldbackground="#e0ffff", background="#e0ffff")
            widget.configure(style="CyanLight.TCombobox")
        else:  # Other options selected
            style.configure("Default.TCombobox", fieldbackground="white", background="white")
            widget.configure(style="Default.TCombobox")

    def update_combobox_style(self, event=None):
        """Update the style of the Combobox when selection changes."""
        self.set_combobox_background(self.combobox)


# Main application runner
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = ComboboxColorChanger(root)
    root.mainloop()

Please can someone explain why this code for dynamically change a combobox background color doesn't work ? thanks

Some styles may not be applied to all themes, so try using another theme.


Please can someone explain why this code for dynamically change a
combobox background color doesn't work

The problem can be  fixed.

Avoid using color and then prepend "TCombobox".
Insert style.theme_use('clam') following ttk.style.
Eliminate the keyword state="readonly" to stop the color from being
altered.
Use style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground='orange',
background="yellow", foreground='white') instead in
set_combobox_background function.
Eliminate widget.configure in the set_combobox_background
function
I include this elif value == "Option 2": if you prefer.

Snippet:
def set_combobox_background(self, widget=None) -> None:
    """Set the background color of the Combobox based on its selection state."""
    value = widget.get()
    print(value)
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use('clam')
    
    if value == "Option 1":  # Option 1 selected
       style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground='orange', background= "yellow",foreground='white')
    elif value == "Option 2":  # No option selected
        style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground='cyanLight', background= "green",foreground='white')            
    else:  # Other options selected
        style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground="white", background="white")

Screenhot

